# How to handle json request in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: android, playframework, httprequest, playframework-1.x

I need to send requests with `json` data parameters from `android app` to `play framework 1.2.5` web service. I could do it with sending normal paramaters as key value. But I would like to send these parameters as json object. I dont know how to define url in `routes` and controller static function to handle json request in `play framework 1.2.5`.

```
public ConnectService(String sngUrl,String searchkey,Double longitude,Double latitude,Double radius){
    try {
        jsonObject.put("searchkey", searchkey);
        jsonObject.put("longitude", longitude); 
        jsonObject.put("latitude", latitude);
        jsonObject.put("radius", radius);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("HATA 1 : "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    jArrayParam = new JSONArray();
    jArrayParam.put(jsonObject); 

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonRequest", jsonObject.toString()));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(sngUrl);
    httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");         
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,"UTF-8" ));//HTTP.UTF_8   
        System.out.println("URLLLLLLLL : "+httppost.getRequestLine());
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                 
        entity = response.getEntity();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("HATA 2 : "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println("HATA 3 : "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("HATA 4 : "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

    }

}
```

And here is my routes and controller method

```
POST     /search                                       Application.search(jsonRequest)

//not for json request
public static void searchproduct(String searchkey,Double longitude,Double latitude,Double radius){
    String d=searchkey+" "+longitude+" "+latitude+" "+radius ;
    renderJSON(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have mistake at declaring Routes and Action in Play apps.

The HTTP response from your android app has one query parameter named `jsonRequest`. So your action in Play apps should be accepted one query parameter named `jsonRequest` too. So, in your Play apps, the solution maybe like following :

**Routes** :

```
# Associate to searchproduct action method
POST     /search        Application.searchproduct
```

**Controller** :

```
//not for json request
public static void searchproduct(String jsonRequest) {
    // convert string to JSON object using org.json.JSONObject
    org.json.JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonRequest);

    // get all the json element
    String searchkey = jsonObject.getString("searchkey")
    Double radius = jsonObject.getDouble("radius")
    ...... // get the rest element

    // here maybe the rest of logic such as, construct JSON and render
    ......
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722733/getting-string-value-from-json-object-android) maybe a useful reference for you.

Comment: thanks it worked. I had also a mistake at my httppost header. I should had been like this httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");