# Android: How do I show "User already exist" message using JSON?

Tags: php, android

I want to insert a record in database and also same time it checks user already exist or not in database using json,but it dose not show proper message. When I am running the app it not show message. How to show this message using json?

**Here is my Code**

```
           public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                private Context context;
                Boolean error, success;

                public SignupActivity(Context context) {
                    this.context = context;
                }

                protected void onPreExecute() {

                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                    String fullName = arg0[0];
                  //  String userName = arg0[1];
                    String passWord = arg0[1];
                    String phoneNumber = arg0[2];
                    String emailAddress = arg0[3];

                    String link;
                    String data;
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                    String result;

                    try {
                        data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
                    //    data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
                        data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
                        data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
                        data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");

                    link = "http://xyz/reg/tryrr.php" + data;

                        URL url = new URL(link);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                        result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        return result;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                     // return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                       // return null;
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                    String jsonStr = result;

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");

                        if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted, fill all records.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            }

            //php file

            <?php
            // array for JSON response
            $response = array();
            // include db connect class
            //require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db_name");

            // connecting to db
            //$db = new DB_CONNECT();

            // check for required fields
            if (isset($_GET['fullname']) && isset($_GET['password']) && isset($_GET['phonenumber']) && isset($_GET['emailaddress'])) {

            $fullName = $_GET['fullname'];
            //$userName = $_GET['username'];
            $passWord = $_GET['password'];
            $phoneNumber = $_GET['phonenumber'];
            $emailAddress = $_GET['emailaddress'];

            // mysql inserting a new row
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users10 (fullname,password,phone,email)
            SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$fullName', '$passWord', '$phoneNumber','$emailAddress') AS tmp
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT phone FROM users10 WHERE phone = '$phoneNumber' 
            )");

            if ($result) {
                // successfully inserted into database
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered to MEMS.";

                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
            } 
            else {
                // failed to insert row
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "User Exist";

                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            } else {
            // required field is missing
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
            }
?>
```

Kindly provide your suggestions.

Comment: This question all ready posted..

Comment: but its still not displaying correct output,please help.

Comment: @mukund: your question is not clear. please explain more

Comment: @mukund can you post your result String

Comment: I want to register a record into database the query is executed here,but the problem is when new user registered it show success message but when the user is already exist then also it shows success message, here i want to show user already exist message, how?

Comment: @mukund check the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set different type of response if user already exists. For example,

`// failed to insert row
 $response["success"] = -1;
 $response["message"] = "User already exists";`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722733/getting-string-value-from-json-object-android.. this might hep you

Answer (score 0):

You will get response like this.

```
{"success":1,"message":"You are successfully registered to MEMS."}
```

Make some changes in `onPostExecute()`

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        String jsonStr = result;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String query_result = jsonObj.getString("success");
            String message_result = jsonObj.getString("message");

            if (query_result.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (query_result.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted, fill all records.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mukund whats logcat saying?

Comment: at com.example.user.mangoair11.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)

Comment: java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked

Comment: paste complete logcat.

Comment: i am not able to paste here

Comment: I tried again this code it shows "Data could not be inserted, fill all records." message for any case

Comment: @mukund it means there is some problem while manipulating database.

Comment: before coming to android integration first send data through browser and then check its output using `echo` result then integrate it with android.

Comment: I checked the query functioning right but unble to show proper message.

Comment: see result like this  `echo json_encode($result);` and `echo $result`