# How to extract nested values from JSON received from GoogleDistanceMatrix API in Java?

Tags: java, json, api, distance, google-distancematrix-api

Trying to parse the following JSON return to java usable code:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361951
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 51 mins",
                  "value" : 13876
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}


      // Parse the whole JSON result.
      JSONObject o1 =(JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(outputString);

      JSONArray a1 = (JSONArray) o1.get("rows");//2
      for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
          JSONObject o2 = (JSONObject) a1.get(i);//3
          JSONArray a2 = (JSONArray) o2.get("elements");//4
          for (int j = 0; j < a2.size(); j++) {
              JSONObject o3 = (JSONObject) a2.get(j);//3
              JSONArray a3 = (JSONArray) o3.get("distance");//4
              for(int k =0; k < a3.size(); k++) {
              System.out.println(((JSONObject) a3.get(k)).get(
                      "text").toString());//5
              }

          }

      }
```

I would like to access **text** value of **distance** and also **text** value of **duration** . I found code to access distance and duration but when I added the third for loop following the example of the old ones I get this expection

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

At this line:

```
   JSONArray a3 = (JSONArray) o3.get("distance");//4
```

Any help or suggestions on how do it in other ways? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject because its not array

```
JSONObject a3 = (JSONObject) o3.get("distance");
```

then

```
  String text=a3.getString("text");
  String value=a3.getString("value");
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response @sasikumar but is says
getString is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: Same. I think that JSONObject just doesn't have a getString method

Comment: its correct only ..refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722733/getting-string-value-from-json-object-android

Comment: I have tried mate but not enough reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @sasikumar

```
JSONObject a3 = (JSONObject) o3.get("distance");
String text = null;
text= (String) a3.get("text");
value=(String )a4.get("text");
```

That solved it for me.