# Get simple string from JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm new to Java. Geting simple answer from server

```
{"response":"ok"}
```

I can successfully output answer from above in virtual device in Android Studio 3 with:

```
try {
...
String finalJson = buffer.toString();
return finalJson;
}catch...
```

Now I want to display only `ok` from server response.
As I understood from [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1), I need to write in `try` this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("response");
return aJsonString;
```

But getting

```
error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I even tried this [Getting String Value from Json Object Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722733/getting-string-value-from-json-object-android) to be sure that this is not array.

Comment: I just ran your code, works fine. Are you sure this is the code which is causing you the problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because  ( String finalJson = buffer.toString();
return finalJson;  ) working and I want to manipulate with only one variable..

Comment: I use API 22 version and AVD with Android 5.1.1.  Maybe this cause error?

Comment: No, its nothing with the android sdk or emulator.

Comment: You are getting the exception when you are creating the `jObject'. Most probably something is wrong with the `finalJson` string.

Comment: Explanation of downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error

> error: unreported exception JSONException; must be caught or declared
>   to be thrown

means that you have a non catched JSON Exception. You should catch JSONException in your catch block

```
try {
    return buffer.toString();
} catch (JSONException exception) {
    Log.d("JSONException", "Json exception catched :".concat(exception.getMessage()));
} finally {
    return "Json error";
}
```

or either throws your exception to your method :

```
public String methodName(Buffer buffer) throws JSONException(){
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using only catch (MalformedURLException e) and catch (IOException e)