# How Can I Parse Json And Create An List in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-json

I am a beginner at the android studio I want to parse JSON data and display it in an array.

My Adapter Code

```
public String[] lst_title = {
    "COSMONAUT",
    "SATELITE",
    "GALAXY",
    "ROCKET"
};
```

I want to replace json data with these values
Like These

```
public String[] lst_title = {
    "json name 1",
    "json name 2",
    "json name 3",
    "json name 4"
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting String Value from Json Object Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722733/getting-string-value-from-json-object-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)